# MBP Retina 13", very contrast images stays on the screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a weird issue with my MBP, not that it causes any discomfort or troubles, just want to make sure it isn't something serious.

I don't even know how to exactly describe the problem, but only can say that when I open some white image and then switch to gray app, I can clearly see shadows of previous image.

I have MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

I uploaded video on YouTube which shows the issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBzi9Qzlxew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the Ghosting-Effece, even though I can't watch the Video because it says it´s private.
This effect can happen, when your screen shows the same image over an longer period. It is visible, when you switch to a blank image.

This problem is covered by your warranty from apple. The will most likely change the display for a new one.

Comment: Fixed the video link. Yeah, just googled ghosting, looks like lg screens affected by this issue. Thanks!